# How to reserve disk space for download and extraction?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

Our flutter app is already downloading and extracting ZIP archives to the device storage on Windows, iOS and Android. We use the Flutter [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) download manager and flutter [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) lib to extract.

Now, customer would like to reserve device storage space. I found an [old article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160714-00/?p=93875) from a Windows tech blog laying out that download managers create an open file handle with a set size of the estimated download size.

Is there already any way to reserve device storage in Flutter or Dart, or is it possible to set the size of an open file handle the way they describe in this tech blog?